# CherryPy Sessions and large objects?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy Webapp that I originally wrote using file based sessions. From time to time I store potentially large objects in the session, such as the results of running a report - I offer the option to download report results in a variety of formats, and I don't want to re-run the query when the user selects a download due to the potential of getting different data. While using file based sessions, this worked fine.

Now I am looking at the potential of bringing a second server online, and as such I need to be able to share session data between the servers, for which it would appear that using the memchached session storage type is the most appropriate. I briefly looked at using a PostgreSQL storage type, but this option was VERY poorly documented, and from what I could find, may well be broken. So I implemented the memcached option.

Now, however, I am running into a problem where, when I try to save certain objects to the session, I get an "AssertionError: Session data for id xxx not set". I'm assuming that this is due to the object size exceeding some arbitrary limit set in the CherryPy session backend or memcached, but I don't really know since the exception doesn't tell me WHY it wasn't set. I have increased the object size limit in memcached to the maximum of 128MB to see if that helped, but it didn't - and that's probably not a safe option anyway.

So what's my solution here? Is there some way I can use the memcached session storage to store arbitrarily large objects? Do I need to "roll my own" DB based or the like solution for these objects? Is the problem potentially NOT size based? Or is there another option I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use mysql for handling my cherrypy sessions.  As long as the object is serializeable (can be pickled) you can store it as a blob (binary large object) in mysql.  Here's the code you would want to use for mysql session storage...

https://bitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com/Lawouach/cherrypy/20111008/936/mysqlsession.py?Signature=gDmkOlAduvIZS4WHM2OVgh1WVuU%3D&Expires=1424822438&AWSAccessKeyId=0EMWEFSGA12Z1HF1TZ82

```
"""
MySQLdb session module for CherryPy by Ken Kinder <http://kenkinder.com/>

Version 0.3, Released June 24, 2000.

Copyright (c) 2008-2009, Ken Kinder
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

    * Neither the name of the Ken Kinder nor the names of its contributors
    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
    without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
"""
import MySQLdb
import cPickle as pickle
import cherrypy
import logging
import threading

__version__ = '0.2'

logger = logging.getLogger('Session')

class MySQLSession(cherrypy.lib.sessions.Session):
    ##
    ## These can be over-ridden by config file
    table_name = 'web_session'
    connect_arguments = {}

    SCHEMA = """create table if not exists %s (
            id varchar(40),
            data text,
            expiration_time timestamp
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB;"""

    _database = None

    def __init__(self, id=None, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('Initializing MySQLSession with %r' % kwargs)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(MySQLSession, k, v)

        self.db = self.get_db()
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        super(MySQLSession, self).__init__(id, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def get_db(cls):
        ##
        ## Use thread-local connections
        local = threading.local()
        if hasattr(local, 'db'):
            return local.db
        else:
            logger.debug("Connecting to %r" % cls.connect_arguments)
            db = MySQLdb.connect(**cls.connect_arguments)
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(cls.SCHEMA % cls.table_name)
            db.commit()
            local.db = db

            return db

    def _load(self):
        logger.debug('_load %r' % self)
        # Select session data from table
        self.cursor.execute('select data, expiration_time from %s '
                            'where id = %%s' % MySQLSession.table_name, (self.id,))
        row = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            (pickled_data, expiration_time) = row
            data = pickle.loads(pickled_data)

            return data, expiration_time
        else:
            return None

    def _save(self, expiration_time):
        logger.debug('_save %r' % self)
        pickled_data = pickle.dumps(self._data)

        self.cursor.execute('select count(*) from %s where id = %%s and expiration_time > now()' % MySQLSession.table_name, (self.id,))
        (count,) = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if count:
            self.cursor.execute('update %s set data = %%s, '
                                'expiration_time = %%s where id = %%s' % MySQLSession.table_name,
                                (pickled_data, expiration_time, self.id))
        else:
            self.cursor.execute('insert into %s (data, expiration_time, id) values (%%s, %%s, %%s)' % MySQLSession.table_name,
                                (pickled_data, expiration_time, self.id))
        self.db.commit()

    def acquire_lock(self):
        logger.debug('acquire_lock %r' % self)
        self.locked = True
        self.cursor.execute('select id from %s where id = %%s for update' % MySQLSession.table_name,
                            (self.id,))
        self.db.commit()

    def release_lock(self):
        logger.debug('release_lock %r' % self)
        self.locked = False
        self.db.commit()

    def clean_up(self):
        logger.debug('clean_up %r' % self)
        self.cursor.execute('delete from %s where expiration_time < now()' % MySQLSession.table_name)
        self.db.commit()

    def _delete(self):
        logger.debug('_delete %r' % self)
        self.cursor.execute('delete from %s where id=%%s' % MySQLSession.table_name, (self.id,))
        self.db.commit()

    def _exists(self):
        # Select session data from table
        self.cursor.execute('select count(*) from %s '
                            'where id = %%s and expiration_time > now()' % MySQLSession.table_name, (self.id,))
        (count,) = self.cursor.fetchone()
        logger.debug('_exists %r (%r)' % (self, bool(count)))
        return bool(count)

    def __del__(self):
        logger.debug('__del__ %r' % self)
        self.db.commit()
        self.db.close()
        self.db = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MySQLSession %r>' % (self.id,)

cherrypy.lib.sessions.MysqlSession = MySQLSession
```

then your webapp.py would look something like this...

```
 from mysqlsession import MySQLSession 
 import cherrypy 
 import logging 

 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) 

 sessionInfo = { 
     'tools.sessions.on': True, 
     'tools.sessions.storage_type': "Mysql", 
     'tools.sessions.connect_arguments': {'db': 'sessions'}, 
     'tools.sessions.table_name': 'session' 
 } 

 cherrypy.config.update(sessionInfo) 

 class HelloWorld: 
     def index(self): 
         v = cherrypy.session.get('v', 1) 
         cherrypy.session['v'] = v+1 
         return "Hello world! %s" % v 

     index.exposed = True 

 cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

If you need to put some object in there do something like this...

```
import pickle

    pickledThing = pickle.dumps(YourObject.GetItems(), protocol=0, fix_imports=False)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your link to the code doesn't work, but from what I can see here, this will suit my purposes admirably, with only minor tweaks to make it work with PostgreSQL rather than MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to store a reference to the object stored in Memcache and then pull it back when you need it, rather than relying on the state to handle the loading / saving.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good start, but leaves the questions a) how/where do I store the object so either server can access it (db perhaps?) and b) how do I handle getting rid of the object when the session expires?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have explained I can conclude that conceptually it isn't a good idea to mix user sessions and a cache. What sessions are mostly designed for is holding state of user identity. Thus it has security measures, locking, to avoid concurrent changes, and other aspects. Also a session storage is usually volatile. Thus if you mean to use sessions as a cache you should understand how sessions really work and the consequences are.

What I suggest you to do it to establish normal caching of your domain model that produces report data and keep session for identity.

## CherryPy details

Default CherryPy session implementation locks the session data. In the OLAP case your user likely won't be able to perform concurrent requests (open another tab for instance) until the report is completed. There's however an option of manual locking management.

PostgreSQL session storage is broken and may be removed in next releases.

Memcached session storage doesn't implement distributed locking, so make sure you use consistent rule to balance your user across your servers.

Comment: The thing about using a general "cache" rather than session data is that the report results are a) user specific, and b) temporary. Using the session object gives me both of those features automatically. Using something else, I have to implement them myself - which is fine, if that is the best way to do things, but a lot of extra work if not.

Comment: @ibrewster For you requirements a) add userId to the key b) set TTL for the cache entry. It is possible to use session storage for the case as long as you understand its semantics. Yes, it comes automatically, but it doesn't come for free. I provided the details. Btw, with many Python cache libraries caching is as simple as applying a decorator to your method.